# Flatten clipped areas in SVG to transparency?

Tags: svg, icons

I have this SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" enable-background="new 0 0 32 32" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="main">
    <clipPath id="clip_mask">
      <path d="M20.9262,32C18.5189,30.6,16.9,27.9878,16.9,25c0,-4.4735,3.6265,-8.1,8.1,-8.1c2.9878,0,5.6,1.6189,7,4.0262V0L0,0l0,32H20.9262z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g id="icon" clip-path="url(#clip_mask)">
      <g id="transformed_icon" transform="translate(-1 -1)">
        <path d="M26.7,30.5H5.3c-0.4418,0,-0.8,-0.3582,-0.8,-0.8V2.3c0,-0.4418,0.3582,-0.8,0.8,-0.8h21.4c0.4418,0,0.8,0.3582,0.8,0.8v27.4C27.5,30.1418,27.1418,30.5,26.7,30.5z" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#6D6E71" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="1"/>
        <path d="M8.5,8.5h15M8.5,11.5h15M8.5,14.5h15M8.5,17.5h15M8.5,20.5h15M8.5,23.5h15" fill="none" stroke="#3E79B4" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="1"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="overlay">
      <path d="M25,18c-3.866,0,-7,3.134,-7,7c0,3.866,3.134,7,7,7s7,-3.134,7,-7C32,21.134,28.866,18,25,18zM26,29.8c0,0.1105,-0.0895,0.2,-0.2,0.2h-1.6c-0.1105,0,-0.2,-0.0895,-0.2,-0.2v-6.6c0,-0.1105,0.0895,-0.2,0.2,-0.2h1.6c0.1105,0,0.2,0.0895,0.2,0.2V29.8zM26,21.5c0,0.1105,-0.0895,0.2,-0.2,0.2h-1.6c-0.1105,0,-0.2,-0.0895,-0.2,-0.2v-1.3c0,-0.1105,0.0895,-0.2,0.2,-0.2h1.6c0.1105,0,0.2,0.0895,0.2,0.2V21.5z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#3E79B4"/>
      <path d="M26,20.2c0,-0.1105,-0.0895,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2h-1.6c-0.1105,0,-0.2,0.0895,-0.2,0.2v1.3c0,0.1105,0.0895,0.2,0.2,0.2h1.6c0.1105,0,0.2,-0.0895,0.2,-0.2V20.2z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
      <path d="M26,23.2c0,-0.1105,-0.0895,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2h-1.6c-0.1105,0,-0.2,0.0895,-0.2,0.2v6.6c0,0.1105,0.0895,0.2,0.2,0.2h1.6c0.1105,0,0.2,-0.0895,0.2,-0.2V23.2z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

It is an icon with an overlay in the bottom-right corner. There is a clip-gap between the main icon area and the overlay area. This clip-gap is displayed correctly in Affinity Designer 1.5.3.69:

[image: Screenshot Affinity Designer]

But unfortunately, many other programs don't recognize the clip-gap, so they don't display it. For example, here is a screenshot from LibreOffice Draw:

[image: Screenshot LibreOffice Draw]

So, is it possible to "flatten" the clipped area in the SVG to the same background transparency as the icon background? This would make the SVG clip-gap visible and transparent in such incompatible programs and would allow programs which don't support clipped areas in SVG to render the clipped area as transparency.

Comment: I've found a practical but cumbersome and time-consuming solution: Since the SVG is displayed correctly in Affinity Designer, I print the SVG in Affinity Designer to a PDF printer driver. Then I reimport the PDF in Affinity Designer and export it as SVG. Then I can import the SVG in a renderer which doesn't support clipping and it is rendered perfectly. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a practical but cumbersome and time-consuming solution: Since the SVG is displayed correctly in Affinity Designer, I print the SVG in Affinity Designer to a PDF printer driver. Then I reimport the PDF in Affinity Designer and export it as SVG. Then I can import the SVG in a renderer which doesn't support clipping and it is rendered perfectly. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to re-use a clip shape to make the clipped area transparent using a filter. However, I very much doubt that a renderer that can't handle clipping properly will be able to handle a filter. But here's how you would do that:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" enable-background="new 0 0 32 32" xml:space="preserve">
  
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip_mask">
      <path id="original-clip-shape" d="M20.9262,32C18.5189,30.6,16.9,27.9878,16.9,25c0,-4.4735,3.6265,-8.1,8.1,-8.1c2.9878,0,5.6,1.6189,7,4.0262V0L0,0l0,32H20.9262z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
    </clipPath>
    
    <filter id="transparentize">
       <feImage xlink:href="#original-clip-shape" x="0" y="0"/>
       <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <g id="main">

    <g id="icon" clip-path="url(#clip_mask)">
      <g id="filter-layer" filter="url(#transparentize)">
      <g id="transformed_icon" transform="translate(-1 -1)">
        <path d="M26.7,30.5H5.3c-0.4418,0,-0.8,-0.3582,-0.8,-0.8V2.3c0,-0.4418,0.3582,-0.8,0.8,-0.8h21.4c0.4418,0,0.8,0.3582,0.8,0.8v27.4C27.5,30.1418,27.1418,30.5,26.7,30.5z" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#6D6E71" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="1"/>
        <path d="M8.5,8.5h15M8.5,11.5h15M8.5,14.5h15M8.5,17.5h15M8.5,20.5h15M8.5,23.5h15" fill="none" stroke="#3E79B4" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="1"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
    <g id="overlay">
      <path d="M25,18c-3.866,0,-7,3.134,-7,7c0,3.866,3.134,7,7,7s7,-3.134,7,-7C32,21.134,28.866,18,25,18zM26,29.8c0,0.1105,-0.0895,0.2,-0.2,0.2h-1.6c-0.1105,0,-0.2,-0.0895,-0.2,-0.2v-6.6c0,-0.1105,0.0895,-0.2,0.2,-0.2h1.6c0.1105,0,0.2,0.0895,0.2,0.2V29.8zM26,21.5c0,0.1105,-0.0895,0.2,-0.2,0.2h-1.6c-0.1105,0,-0.2,-0.0895,-0.2,-0.2v-1.3c0,-0.1105,0.0895,-0.2,0.2,-0.2h1.6c0.1105,0,0.2,0.0895,0.2,0.2V21.5z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#3E79B4"/>
      <path d="M26,20.2c0,-0.1105,-0.0895,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2h-1.6c-0.1105,0,-0.2,0.0895,-0.2,0.2v1.3c0,0.1105,0.0895,0.2,0.2,0.2h1.6c0.1105,0,0.2,-0.0895,0.2,-0.2V20.2z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
      <path d="M26,23.2c0,-0.1105,-0.0895,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2h-1.6c-0.1105,0,-0.2,0.0895,-0.2,0.2v6.6c0,0.1105,0.0895,0.2,0.2,0.2h1.6c0.1105,0,0.2,-0.0895,0.2,-0.2V23.2z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
    </g>
   </g>

</svg>
```

As far as workarounds go, it's hard to debug renderer specific problems without the renderer. But here are some thoughts:

- It might support clipping but just not support using the stroke as a clip. You could work around this by using a solid circle as the clip-shape.
- it might support masking not clipping. In this case, define a mask that's the inverse of the clip and apply that.
- it might not support clipping or masking at all. In that case, you'll have to just draw the original content as if it was being clipped using markers to shape the ends of your paths. (ugh!)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! But the question was not about what might cause an incompatible renderer to fail but how could the SVG be flattened.

Comment: Sorry - I skipped to the workaround. I'll add a preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your idea! Chrome and Affinity Designer can cope with the `filter` tag. But my application (a licensed product) unfortunately cannot. BTW, why so many SVG vector graphics have inherent transformations like `clipPath` and so on? This makes SVG almost a proprietary format while it should be a widely recognized standard.

Comment: I'm just a web guy - can't speak to other rendering engines :)